# File Writing in php without appending

Tags: php

Following is my piece of code which writes to file.

```
<?php
$fileWrite = fopen("c.txt", "w+");

for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
    $bytes = fwrite($fileWrite, $i);
}

fclose($fileWrite);
```

I am getting `01234`. It means , pointer is `appending to last location`, I  don't  want to append data. Instead need to write `4` in the file.

Comment: Then you have to only write 4 to the file. Put the `fopen` in your loop.

Comment: If you want to write only `4` then why do you need a for loop? you can directly use `fwrite($fileWrite,4);` without any loop

Comment: Sometimes I don't understand people. Seems to me like `echo '1'; echo '2'; echo '3'; echo '4';` - 1234 is printed. Why? I want just 4 to be printed...

Comment: to be fair... the for loop might have been to test whether data was being written or appended... its no excuse for posting it, but the point should be made

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to [`ftruncate`](http://php.net/ftruncate) the file before writing to it:

```
ftruncate($fileWrite, 0);
$bytes = fwrite($fileWrite, $i);
```

This is obviously pretty pointless to do in a loop, but I expect you know that.

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend using [`file_put_contents`](https://www.php.net/file_put_contents) for this simple task. It's easier to use and will not append to the end of the file (unless specified that way).

Comment: I love how it's `fopen` and `fwrite` but `file_put_contents`. Gotta love PHP.

Comment: Convention is nothing :D

Comment: I have no idea why people keep complaining about a lack of conventions in PHP. There are *so many* conventions to choose from!

Comment: @Dugi file_put_content is not putting content it is creating file but not putting content

Comment: Umm, not really. If the file exists, it will be overwritten with the new content which will be specified in the second function parameter. That's the reason why I linked you to the PHP docs, to read what the function really does.